# How to define type of objects that all extend a common trait with a recursive type signature

Tags: scala, elastic4s

I wrote a method that returns objects that all extend a common trait.  I want to specify the return type to be objects with that trait.  The complication is that the trait has a recursive type signature.

In particular, I am using [elastic4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/) and looking at the [aggregationDefinition trait](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/elastic4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/aggregations.scala#L62).  The trait definition is:

```
trait AggregationDefinition[+Self <: AggregationDefinition[Self, B], B <: AggregationBuilder[B]]
```

And a simplified version of my method is:

```
def asAggregation(): AggregationDefinition = {
  aggType match {
    case "terms" => aggregation.terms(aggName).field(key)
    case "cardinality" => aggregation.cardinality(aggName).field(key)
  }
}
```

The complication lies with AggregationDefinition, that it requires type parameters:

```
Error: trait AggregationDefinition takes type parameters
```

I am confused by the recursion and the cross reference in the trait definition, and it is unclear to me what the type parameters should be. What should I use for the type parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The `AggregationDefinition` need **type Bound**(see the type signature), you can use `AbstractAggregationDefinition`, like:

```
def asAggregation(): AbstractAggregationDefinition = {
  aggType match {
    case "terms" => aggregation.terms(aggName).field(key)
    case "cardinality" => aggregation.cardinality(aggName).field(key)
  }
}
```

Comment: What you are suggesting works just fine.  However, I need to call `aggregations` on the objects returned by `asAggregation`.  I want to return `AggregationDefinition` because that is where `aggregations` is defined.